# Website header is info is showing different in firefox

Tags: html, css

I have created a PHP file, in which i have set the css for the paragraph tag to white. When it is opened in IE it works fine. But when it opened in firefox it shows as black. I have given below the code. Is there anything to be modified or added.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title></title>
<meta name="" content="">
<style type="text/css">
.common
{
font-family:"tahoma";
font-size:11px;
color:"#FFFFFF";
}
#city
{
color:"#000000";
}
.header
{
background: scroll 0 0 #7D1919;
width:auto;
margin-top:-8px;
margin-left:-8px;
height:27px;
margin-right:-8px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header">
<table>
<tbody><tr class="common">
<td>
<p>&nbsp; &nbsp; Select your city :&nbsp;</p>
</td>
<td>
<select id="city" class="common" style="width:100px;border-collapse:collapse;" align="right">
<option selected="selected">chennai</option>
</select>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>


</body></html>
```

Thanks,
Lokesh.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure which version of IE this is working for you, but those color values should not have quotes around them.

Quotation marks are rarely used in CSS, namely for wrapping font names that have spaces, and optionally for wrapping `url()` sources. There are a few other uses as well, but they aren't used to wrap hex values.

Remove those quotes and see if that helps. i.e. `"#000000"` to `#000000`

Comment: Thanks for the update that helps. Now i got an another problem, the postioning of the header the margin-top,left,right behaves differently in firefox and IE8. ANy idea on this?

Comment: This only happened after you removed the quotes, and no other changes were made? If so, it could be because now your CSS is valid, whereas before it was not. In any case, it is definitely [a separate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), after you spend a little time trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the Quotes for the color code

```
color:#FFFFFF;
```